# How to select and display custom result?

Tags: hibernate, jsf, plsql

Below is list of mapped tables in  **hibernate.reveng.xml**:

```
  <table-filter match-name="UNI_MAJORS"/>
  <table-filter match-name="SKILLS"/>
  <table-filter match-name="PROFILES_JOB_EXPERIENCES"/>
  <table-filter match-name="PROFILES_EDU"/>
  <table-filter match-name="PROFILES_SKILLS"/>
  <table-filter match-name="UNI_DEGREES"/>
  <table-filter match-name="HIGHER_EDU_CENTERS"/>
  <table-filter match-name="COMPANIES"/>
  <table-filter match-name="PROFILES"/>
  <table-filter match-name="CITIES"/>
  <table-filter match-name="STATES"/>
```

I'm using ***.hbm.xml** files, not annotation.
every thing is working properly I just want to display a result like below which is not in non of above mapped classes:

```
select p.profile_id,pj.exp_id,p.full_name,ct.city_name
 ,c.company_name,pj.title,pj.date_from,pj.date_to
from PROFILES p
join PROFILES_JOB_EXPERIENCES pj on p.profile_id=pj.profile_ref
left outer join COMPANIES c on pj.company_ref=c.company_id
left outer join CITIES ct on ct.city_id=c.city_ref
```

I tried below method in controller class:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class ProfileExperiences implements Serializable {
      //code...(not need for display here)

      public List getExpList() {
      session = sessionFactory.openSession();
      transaction = session.beginTransaction();
      List<ProfileExpsView> lst = session.createQuery("Select p.profileId as profileId, pj.expId as expId,"
            + "p.fullName as fullName, cmp.cities.cityName as cityName,cmp.companyName as companyName,"
            + "pj.title as title,pj.dateFrom as dateFrom,pj.dateTo as dateTo "
            + "From Profiles p "
            + "join p.profilesJobExperienceses pj "
            + "join pj.companies cmp "
            + "where p.profileId=:p_profileId").setParameter("p_profileId",
            profiles.getProfileId()).list();
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
    return lst;
    }
    //Code...(not need for display here)
  }
```

and in my JSF page I use this:

```
<h:panelGrid>
            <h:dataTable id="expsList" value="#{profileExperiences.expList}" var="exp">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">City</f:facet>
                    #{exp.cityName}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="hearde">Company</f:facet>
                    #{exp.companyName}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Job Title</f:facet>
                    #{exp.title}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Start Date</f:facet>
                    #{exp.dateFrom}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">End date</f:facet>
                    #{exp.dateTo}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:commandButton value="X" action="#{profileExperiences.deleteProExp(exp.expId)}">
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

But nothing is displayed, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is clearly associated with Hibernate (and/or the associated back-end database, if the query statement fails either way). JSF is purely a superfluous subject in this case. You are returning a non-generic `java.util.List` from the method `getExpList()`. If you are returning a list of tuple rows (thus not a list of objects of a fully qualified mapped entity) then, there are several ways to do this. In a nutshell, you can return a `List<Object[]>`, `List<Tuple>` or you can map the result list to a class of objects using a constructor query and thus, returning a `List<YourClass>`.

Comment: @Tiny thanks for your comment, `List<Object[]>` also didn't bring the result into my jsf page I don't know exactly what is the problem, I'll try `List<YourClass>` like below answer I think it's better in case I need in different page and controller classes.

Comment: Well I mentioned those result list strategies `List<Object[]>`, `List<Tuple>` and `List<YourClass>` purely based on JPA. In the context of plain core native Hibernate, the thing might differ somewhat.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you very much for the edit and for the comment, I was new, I'll try in next times, however the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can return List and refer objects with the index

```
 List<Object[]> lst = session.createQuery("Select cmp.cities.cityName as cityName,cmp.companyName as companyName,"
        + "pj.title as title,pj.dateFrom as dateFrom,pj.dateTo as dateTo "
        + "From Profiles p "
        + "join p.profilesJobExperienceses pj "
        + "join pj.companies cmp "
        + "where p.profileId=:p_profileId").setParameter("p_profileId",
        profiles.getProfileId()).list();
```

in JSF Page you can refer like **#{item[0]}**    [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484963/primefaces-filling-datatable-with-listobject)

```
<h:panelGrid>
        <h:dataTable id="expsList" value="#{profileExperiences.expList}" var="exp">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">City</f:facet>
                #{exp[0]}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="hearde">Company</f:facet>
                 #{exp[1]}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Job Title</f:facet>
                #{exp[2]}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Start Date</f:facet>
                #{exp[3]}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">End date</f:facet>
                #{exp[4]}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <h:commandButton value="X" action="#{profileExperiences.deleteProExp(exp.expId)}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"></f:ajax>
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGrid>
```